# Jumping to anchor in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

Situation:

First: **iframe** with id *miframe*, displaying a site with the anchor called *suchen*, i.e.

```
<div id="suchen"></div>.
```

Second. Parent frame.

Goal: Make a link within the parent frame looking like

```
<a class="LINK0" title="" href="javascript:springen('suchen');">w/e</a>
```

make the content in the **iframe** be scrolled to the anchor *suchen*. My approach.

```
function springen(anker) { 
    var childWindow =  document.getElementById("miframe").contentWindow;

    // this should emulate a click on the ptAnchor DIV's child A HREF.
    //childWindow.document.getElementById(anker).firstChild.click();
    //childWindow.document.getElementById(anker).scrollIntoView();
    // alternatively, this will simply scroll the child window to the top-left corner
    //childWindow.scrollTo(0,200);
}
```

`childWindow.scrollTo(0,200);` works in so far, that scroll happens to 200. 
But I need scrolling to the very anchor, wherever it is in the **iframe**. Ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Normally you would use a link like `<a href="#your_anchor_name_or_id">Go to the anchor</a>`. If you want to do this using JavaScript, you can change the value of `window.location.hash`. The following code should do that within a frame:

```
document.getElementById("the_id_of_your_iframe").contentWindow.location.hash = "your_anchor_name_or_id";
```

If you don't want to change the hash value, there is [an example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location#Example_6_Using_bookmarks_without_changing_the_hash_property). You can modify it for an iframe.

Comment: I get this error:
Uncaught DOMException: Permission denied to access property "hash" on cross-origin object
On Firefox 91.6.0esr

Answer (score 4):

The following code should scroll the iframe to the anchor's position:

```
function springen(anker) { 
    var childWindow =  document.getElementById("miframe").contentWindow;
    childWindow.scrollTo(0,childWindow.document.getElementById('suchen').offsetTop);
}
```

**Edit:**

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pkvhw/6/

Comment: Without trying... but I was thinking that you ought to loop through all its `offsetParent`s and sum up their `offsetTop`s.