# how to pass value to player vídeojs click within a iframe

Tags: jquery, html, function, iframe, carousel

I have the situation with a carousel. Inside of it there is an iframe that load the content output of my site, cause i need that pages just be independents, in this case i have a video in a second slide. I'm using Owl Carousel for this. When i navigate on the slides i need to my video call a function that pause himself. I´m using the API from the plugin Videojs that already make this works, but when i add a iframe for this project it gaves me troubles.

So, how can i call the same function from the Videojs to my parent page?

Here is a [example1](http://www.grupouninter.com.br/projetoscorporativos/portal/teste/pos/) using include php files. Works!

Here is a [example2](http://www.grupouninter.com.br/projetoscorporativos/portal/teste/pos2/) using iframe. Don't works!

Thanks a lot, folks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to specify in your javascript code that the anchor is inside of the iframe.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.owl-prev, .owl-next').click(function() {
                var myPlayer = _V_("pages/page02.php#video_uninter1");
                myPlayer.pause();
            });
        });
```

Look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893256/jumping-to-anchor-in-iframe).

Comment: cause of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you can only access elements of an iframe that is on the same domain that your main page