# Iframe inside a rails app executing javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, iframe

Trying to make iframe work in the rails 3.2 app. I have a page with two columns. On left I have applications and on the right I have resume. when user click resume button on left. The iframe on the left gets loaded with the resume page which comes from a different controller and action. Now the resume page in i frame uses JS for navigation (like sliding to employment, education etc part) That Javascript is not working. When resume page is viewed on its own webpage , everything works fine. But inside iframe JS is not working.

Code is as follows,
Inside Main page

```
<iframe id="open_here" name="open_here"></iframe>
```

resume button on the left side

```
<%= link_to "test", {:controller => 'applicants',  :action => 'applicantresume'}, {:target => "open_here"} %>
```

Is there anything I am missing.

Comment: Okay, My mistake. JS is working. The issue is anchor tags which are used for navigation in the iframe. So for example the iframe has a tag name /#education as home page. When i press the resume button on the left side column, the iframe gets loaded with resume but parent url get appened with the xyz.com/#education. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try this one:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893256/jumping-to-anchor-in-iframe