# force an iframe to scroll to anchors passed by querystring in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, iframe

I have a php page A, inside this page I have an iframe with a source (attribute src="") like `<iframe id="iframe_book" name="iframe_book" src="book.html"></iframe>`

The "book.html" is a page with a lot of text divided in sections and contain html anchors (`<a name="anchor-1"></a>`) before each block of text

I have another php page B with a form that pass a variable (#anchor-1), that is an anchor name, to page A.

Inside page A I pass this variable to the iframe, editing the source of the iframe: `<iframe id="iframe_book" name="iframe_book" src="book.html#anchor-1"></iframe>`

So I expect the page book.html inside the iframe will scroll to the anchor passed, like normally a html page do.
I want this will work with all the browsers; with Chrome works (iframe scroll to the anchor) but with Firefox not.

The question is: how can I force the iframe to scroll to anchors passed by querystring in Firefox, maybe with javascript or jquery?

I found solutions to force the use of anchors with links inside the iframe page "book.html" but not for my case of anchors passed by querystring.

Firefox issue:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=638598

force the use of anchors with links inside the iframe page:
http://matthewmanela.com/blog/making-linking-between-anchors-in-an-iframe-work-in-firefox-11-and-above/

Comment: This is a solution based on plain Javascript.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893256/jumping-to-anchor-in-iframe)

Comment: Tried but didn't worked.    I added to page A this script: `function scroll_anchor(anchor) { var childWindow =  document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow;
     if( childWindow.document.getElementById(anchor) != null ){
      childWindow.scrollTo(0,childWindow.document.getElementById(anchor).offsetTop);
     }
    }
    
<?php if( $request_anchor != '' ){?> scroll_anchor('<?php echo substr($request_anchor,1); ?>');
<?php } ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved adding this script into page A after the iframe tag.

```
<?php
        //#anchor-1
        $anchor = isset($_REQUEST['anchor']) ? $_REQUEST['anchor'] : '';
        if( $anchor != '' ){
?>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
        function scroll_anchor(anchor){
        parent.frames['iframe_book'].location.href = "book.html?"+anchor+"";
        }
        window.onload = function(){
            <?php echo "scroll_anchor('".$anchor."');"; ?>
        }
        </script>
<?php } ?>
```